# how to generate only required classes from XSDs via maven-jaxb

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, jaxb

I have two XSDs where one includes the other, lets call them A and B.

B has a lot of `xs:complexType` definitions and is included by A, however A is interested in using only some of those.

What happens right now is that classes for all types defined in B are generated. 
What i would like to achieve is to generate classes only for types which are directly referenced by A.

I have tried to modify XSD A to import B instead of include but it didn't work out for maven-jaxb plugin.

XSD A import of B:

```
<xs:import schemaLocation="B.xsd" />
```

Plugin setup for generating sources:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-xsd</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>xsd/*.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <strict>true</strict>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-XJsr303Annotations</arg>
                            <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                        </args>
                        <plugins>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                                <version>0.6.3</version>
                            </plugin>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>com.github.krasa</groupId>
                                <artifactId>krasa-jaxb-tools</artifactId>
                                <version>1.1</version>
                            </plugin>
                        </plugins>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I understand there is a way to achieve what i ask with **xjc** from command line, but then the plugins for annotating classes for validation do not trigger.

What i need is a way to generate only required classes while keeping runtime annotations such as `@NotNull` generated by plugins bellow. Can somebody please help with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of the [maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin) here.

What is possible with `xjc` is possible with the `maven-jaxb2-plugin`. You can do all your configuration with `args/arg` alone. So if you believe what you want is possible from the command line, post this command line and we'll figure out how to configure the plugin accordingly.

From what I believe to know, including schemas makes XJC compile the whole set. If it's included, it is *one schema*, just declared in several files. So you'll get all the types generated.

If you change your inclusions to imports and start with a certain top-schema in A, then XJC will probably generate less types in B. But there's no guarantee as I don't believe this behaviour is a part of XJC's public contract. And it does not matter if you use XJC via command-line or via a Maven plugin. It's the same XJC there down under.

What I have the best experience with, is the modular or separate schema compilation:

- https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Modular-Schema-Compilation

Basically, you compile B first and use it as an episode when you compile A. It works with `jaxb:class/@ref` annotations under the hut to point to already existing classes instead of generating them anew.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response. I will provide question with additional details as you suggested and kindly ask you to check the question again. Thank you.

Comment: So it seems that this is not reproducible. My colleague managed to build only referenced classes via xjc in one project month ago but i wasnt interested as annotations were missing. And now we cannot reproduce that O_o